# No sound detected by the internal microphone on a dell laptop

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, dell, alsa, microphone

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell G3 15 3590. Had some problems already with the audio. To make it work I added `snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0` to grub parameters, it made my internal audio work, but not my mic; then I added `options snd-hda-intel model=headset-mic` in alsa-base.conf. With this, my system recognizes internal mic, but no sound is detected. Had gone weeks already trying to find a solution, but nothing until now.

Edit: The sound works without `options snd-hda-intel model=headset-mic`, but still mic don't detect any sound. On Discord voice testing, I hear echos of my internal audio, really weird. And when I plug only a headphone the system switches the input to headphone mic; and if I switch back the input to internal mic then audio stop working too (and still no sound on mic).

Comment: dif you try this :   in alsamixer ,  press F4  to display capture settings and test modifying capture state (space bar) and volume on the different  faders

Comment: I verified that when my headphone is plugged, the internal mic captures sound, however if a select the internal mic, the headphone got mute. And if i unplug the headphone, no mic is recognized. When i add the 'options snd-hda-intel model=headset-mic' to alsa-base.conf, in settings an internal mic appears in inputs, but it dont work and alsamixer shows "this device has no capture configurations".